# why I cannot convert an existing Eclipse project to the dynamic web project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an existing Eclipse java project, and need to export it to the war file for deployment. By googling, it turns out that I need to covert it to a dynamic web project at first. But the menu item for this conversion is disabled. I would like to know why.

Comment: Why cant you just create a new dynamic web project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to edit the project properties and go to project facets. In there you can select the Dynamic Web Module facet.

Comment: thanks, Mul1na. Can you let met know which project properties should be edited?

Comment: it's under the category called 'Project Facets' and the facet is called 'Dynamic Web Module'. You can further configure your project on that screen, specifying your runtime (Tomcat, etc) and your content directory and so on. [Here](http://www.webspheretools.com/sites/webspheretools.nsf/docs/Understanding%20Dynamic%20web%20module%20version%20settings%20in%20Eclipse) are some screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

you need to select the Dynamic Web Module as mut1na said and the java server faces box if you're importing a jsf project. You will probably need to check the runtime too.